# Searching for ObjectID > "xxxx" in MongoDB and Golang

Tags: mongodb, go

I have a throuble with that

```
    opciones := options.Find()
    opciones.SetLimit(10)
    opciones.SetSort(bson.D{{"_id", 1}})

    condicion := bson.M{
        "userid":ID,
        "_id": bson.M{"$gt": LastID},
    }
```

**LastID** is a String that I receive in Body , and I need to paginate for 10 documents

I'm using

```
    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo"
    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo/options"
    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/bson"
    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/bson/primitive"
```

These FIND return NULL  and I have documents.

Thanks

Comment: What's the type of _id in the documents? If it is ObjectId, then you have to convert that string to an ObjectId

Comment: type Parametros struct {
    Email string `bson:"email" json:"email, omitempty"`
    IDLast string `bson:"idlast" json:"idlast, omitempty"`
}

Comment: What is the type of _id in the database documents?

Comment: Is an ObjectID type

Comment: Then you need to parse the string back to an ObjectId

Comment: Yes, my Friend, but my question is that ... how I need to write the CONDICION variable, to work fine.

Comment: Use primitive.ObjectIdFromHex(LastID) to get an ObjectId, and use that in the condition

Comment: Thank but, I'm using this in the IMPORT     "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/bson/primitive" and this lines condicion := bson.M{
        "userid":ID,
        "_id": bson.M{"$gt": primitive.ObjectIdFromHex(LastID)},
    } throws this error bd/bd.go:166:30: undefined: primitive.ObjectIdFromHex

Comment: Now Works !!! I only have to write in separate lines the ObjectID convertion ObjID, _ := primitive.ObjectIDFromHex(LastID)  THANKS !!!